# PlatformApplicationDisabledException

Tags: spring-boot, apple-push-notifications, jhipster, sandbox, javaapns

My application shuts down sometime with the following error in the console:

```
PlatformApplicationDisabledException
```

I've reached out to aws service team to investigate what I was doing wrong in my program.

So, they have replied that:

> PlatformApplicationDisabledException is triggered when the downstream
>   push-notification service rejects the credentials provided with the
>   request.
>
> In your case, the downstream provider is APNS_SANDBOX. Ensure that you
>   are using valid Sandbox credentials with your APNS SNS application.
>
> Apple rejected your credentials, likely due to them being expired, or
>   for a production application.

Can someone guide me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: [What does "PlatformApplicationDisabled" mean?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=170557)